# Java Getting Final Calculated Result from different HashMap for the same object

Tags: java, jsp, dictionary, hashmap

I want to calculate the rating system of camera based on user input. There are actually three kinds of rating mechanism which has to be calculated at the end to get the Final rating.  I have kept each result in different HashMap

Below HashMap has   Camera object  and  Double=Rating value Saying that particular Camera has that Rating on that particular mechanism.

```
//Portalibility Rating Mechanism
1. Map<Camera,Double> portabilityRatedCameraList= 
   PriorityRate.getPortabillityRate(cameralist,portabillity)

//Ease Of Use Rating Mechanism
2. Map<Camera,Double> easeofdCameraList=
PriorityRate.getEaseOfUser(cameralist, easeofuse, manualcontrol);

//UsageRating Mechanism
3. Map<Camera,Double> usageRatedCameraList=
PriorityRate.getUsageRate(cameralist, portabillity, props, manualcontrol);
```

Now Final Rating algorithm is something like

```
Final rate of a camera= portabillityrate + easeofrate + usagerate
```

So, how can I get the particular camera's  final rating? How can I get the values from hashmap 1, 2, 3  for that particular camera?

I am not able to proceed after this line

```
for(int i=0; i<cameralist.size(); i++)
{
 Camera camera=cameralist.get(i)
//How can I get the rating value for the Camera object from above 3 HashMap?

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know how to put and get values in a map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we have the key of all the 3 `Maps` which is `Camera` object so we can get the value by key and total it.As you dnt specify what to do with the result so in below code i printed it.

```
  for(int i=0; i<cameralist.size(); i++)
    {
     Camera camera=cameralist.get(i)
     Object cameraTotal = portabilityRatedCameraList.get(camera) + easeofdCameraList.get(camera) + usageRatedCameraList.get(camera)
     System.out.println("The total rating of the camera "+camera+" is "+(Double)cameraTotal);
    }
```